# 'go ride your highest horse' equivalence?

Tags: idiom-requests

'Go ride your highest horse'. It is used to mean go do whatever you wish I will not comply or listen to what you want. It's like never will I do that, go do as you wish. The idea behind riding your highest horse, is you'll look bigger and scarier or smth suchlike that may force him to comply or do as that person wishes, yet by telling him to 'go ride his highest is simply saying whatever you do I will not comply/I will not be scared with unflinching determination. It's just idioms of the desert. It has nothing to do with get off your high horse, the english idiom.

Comment: Did you have a question?

Comment: The english equivalence of this idiom.

Comment: "Go take a flying leap", I suppose.

Answer (score 1):

There's a crude expression which seems apt. (One which you will find quite a few hits for, but none that I'd regard as being definitive and which I therefore won't include here.) It's actually exceedingly similar in both origin (I would expect) and content to what you're describing. It is:

"***Expletive*** you and the horse you rode in on".

Needless to say, ***Expletive*** is usually replaced by one of a number of slang words referring to sexual intercourse.

The inclusion of the "horse" in this indicates the the speaker doesn't care whether the recipient considers himself to be one of the speaker's "betters" by having a horse to ride rather than walking. (Of course, that notion harks back to olden days, when one had to have a decent amount of money to have a riding horse, but still...)

In meaning, it falls into the same genre as Hot Licks' comment. (Though "take a flying leap" doesn't include any suggestion that the person you say it to is adopting a superior attitude toward you, which seems to be implied in your question.)

Answer (score 0):

A less crude and somewhat closer match would be "Do your worst."  It conveys both defiance and disdain, similar to your description of the "highest horse" expression.  However it is still not quite the same.

From your description of the original expression, this exchange might happen:

- "I don't care how busy you are, I want that report finished by Friday!"
- "Go ride your highest horse."

A response of "Do your worst" would not quite fit this situation, because it is usually said in response to some sort of threat.  The exchange would have to go like this instead:

- "You better finish that report by Friday, or you'll be in huge trouble!"
- "Do your worst."